# How do I embed an input component like e.g. a selectOneMenu into a PickList?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

I am getting the following error when I put the value attribute in the selectOneMenu `value="#{customer.customerType}"`:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'customer' resolved to null

**PickList:**

```
<p:pickList id="customersPL" itemLabel="#{customer.id}"
    itemValue="#{customer}" responsive="true"
    value="#{bean.customersList}" var="customer">

    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter"
        list="#{bean.customersListSource}" />

    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{bean.onTransfer}" />

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
            id="customerType" value="#{customer.customerType}">
            <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{customerType.name}"
                itemValue="#{customerType}"
                value="#{bean.customerTypesList}"
                var="customerType" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

**Bean:**

```
private CustomerType[] customerTypesList = CustomerType.values();
```

**CustomerType Enum:**

```
public static enum CustomerType {
    WHOLESALE("W", "Wholesale"), RETAIL("R", "Retail");

    private String id;
    private String name;

    TipoCliente(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: `[org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler]` looks like OmniFaces, not PrimeFaces.

Comment: Why do you use PrimeFaces and `converter` from OmniFaces?

Comment: I doubt it was meant to be used this way.

Comment: @Geinmachi omnifaces make things too easy

Comment: @Kukeltje Any suggestions

Comment: No, the only suggestion I can give is to rethink your ui design (you are the first to try it this way in about a dozen years)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picklists in general are not intended to contain input 'controls'. So the `p:pickList` was never designed to contain inputs like `h\p:selectonemenu` or even plain `h\p:inputTexts`. So it does not work like you expect it to and that is just unfortunate. Redesigning your ui is the only thing to do.

Comment: I have changed pickList to dataTable

Comment: 'accepting' the answer as  'valid' is the way to signal to others that is the (closest) correct answer, even though it was not the solution you hoped for